# Spring Security: How to get checkbox value from login page in my controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to I get the value of the check box in my loginpage?

In my Jsp I have a remember me check box.

```html
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/amPostLogin" method="POST" modelAttribute="userLogin">
      <form:input type="text" path="username" id="username" placeholder="username"required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
      <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" placeholder="password" required="required"/>
      
      <br><form:checkbox label="Remember Me" path="isRemember" />
      <br><form:checkbox label="Auto Login" path="isAutoLogin"/>
      
      <form:button class="login-button" >Login</form:button>
</form:form>
```

In my Spring Security I have:

```html
@Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/am*")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login_AM")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/amPostLogin")
                    .failureUrl("/login_AM?error=true")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/amChatPage")
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/amLogout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful_AM")
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/am403")
                    .and().httpBasic()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
```

Now I want to get the values of AutoLogin and RememberMe in my controller.
How do I do that?

I tried creating a controller for "/amPostLogin" but for some reason it doesn't get inside the controller. How can I get the value of those checkbox in my controller? Please someone help me. Thank you.

**ANSWER**

Instead of getting the value of checkbox in the controller, I created an AuthenticationSuccessHandler and get the values there.

```html
@Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        boolean isRemember = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("isRemember"));
        boolean isAutoLogin = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("isAutoLogin"));

       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.sendRedirect("amChatPage");
    }
```

Comment: Why you need get your value in controller ?

Comment: I need to get the value for Remember me to store the cookie for prefill value of username and password when the user log out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring mvc your login jsp needs some changes .
1)You login page action should be mapped to j_spring_security_check.htm, spring's UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java intercepts this url for authentication. 
2)Your username and password should be mapped to is j_username and j_password , this above filter expects these fields to be set, you can check the source code.
3)You also need to provide an authentication provider in context.xml
4)You need to define lgtAuthenticationFailureHandler and lgtAuthenticationsuccessHandler. From lgtAuthenticationsuccessHandler you can direct to your home page of application.

This is the login part.You can refer many sites for login authentication in spring.

For cookie part,

what you can do is on click of remember me checkbox , you can write a javascript that will create a remember me cookie with username in it and all other parameters like expiry n all.

when next time the page loads you can write a onload javascript funtion where you can check if remember me cookie exists and based in that you can populate username and tick your remember me checkbox.

This is how i have implemented so you can try this.

Comment: I override the  j_spring_security_check.htm and change is to /amPostLogin that is why in my form it works fine. Everything in my login process works fine. Regarding with the cookie, I don't have any background to javascript that's why I just use java to create a cookie and added in my AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

Comment: ok, so your mapping to controller is working, but if i see your code why are you fetching the cookie from request?? the checkbox is part of form and that is mapped to a model, so i think then you should get remember me value from the model in controller, and then create the cookie over there and set in httpservletresponse. You can refer this link i just came around https://dzone.com/articles/using-cookies-implement

Comment: The reason why I can't get the value in my Controller is that I used the path "/amPostLogin" which is the .loginProcessingUrl() in my Web Security. This path will process the submitted credentials but will NOT pass the Request to Spring MVC and to my controller. That's why I can't access the values in my controller. So instead I just used AuthenticationSuccessHandler.